# UISlider like Apple Music

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

The new Apple Music has very light and minimalist and customized `UISlider`. The `UISlider` image seems to be drawn in the `drawRect()` method of it. How to make something similar?

[image]

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control goes through a great example of how to do almost exactly this. Edit: If you're a Swifty http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift

Comment: @DavidCao could be a solution, but the objective-c is outdated and not interested in developing a solution in swift. thanks anyways.

Comment: @JAL no work in progress, just wondering a solution.

Comment: I actually used the tutorial to make a slider in my app a couple weeks ago, the code isn't outdated at all except for a few property calls. But in general it provides the correct method for doing something like this. Subclass UIControl, and manage the touches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UISlider`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/) exposes properties so you can modify the tint color or images of the “thumb” (the circle part) and the track to the left and right of the thumb. You can also subclass and provide different frames for the track and thumb. You can also adjust these properties on all sliders in your app using [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/).

[This Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6) covers how to customize the appearance of sliders along with many other controls. The gist, in case that link goes down:

```
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb"];

[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```